# Possible to return LinkedIn Degree of Connection from API call?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is it possible to take the current user of an app (and their LinkedIn User ID) and compare them to a database of LinkedIn user IDs and return a list of all LinkedIn user IDs from the database that are second degree connections?

This would allow the user performing the search to see who the best database members for them to reach out to would be.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/connections-api#sample

here is the API that could allow you to do this. **BUT** you will need to apply for the linkedin-partnership program to be allowed to use the V2 api of linkedin.

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs